# Specific version of postgres

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, connection, version

I want to install a specific version of Postgres 10.17 on Ubuntu 20.04

i follow the instuctions and i run those commands

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'


wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -


sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-10
```

But the result i get is version 10.19. I tried also with brew but the same thing happens.

Comment: Just use 10.19 - unless you want to reproduce a bug from 10.17 that was fixed in a later version, there is no need to use an old minor version.

Comment: i need that specific version for production

Comment: No you don't, unless you need to replicate a bug that was fixed in the minor release .18 or .19. All minor releases (of a major release) will behave the same way (except for fixed bugs obviously). And besides: you should not run an outdated release in production anyway.

Comment: Look at https://apt-archive.postgresql.org/